# Spring MVC encode request from Cp1252 to UTF-8

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, encoding

There is a post request to my controller with JSON encoded in `Cp1252`. How can I encode the request body to `UTF-8`? I use Jackson to get a POJO.

Comment: Does the request have a proper `Content-Type` header that identifies the encoding?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I'm able to set it

Comment: Then it ought to work automatically.

Comment: It doesn't. There is mojbake instead. But when i do 
    System.out.println(new String(textFromJson.getBytes("cp1252")));
then all is Ok.

Comment: That sounds like you're sending UTF8 bytes and claiming they're `CP-1252`.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this filter to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>



<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

i had a similar problem and this solved it.